# Sql query for a specific time period

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a mysql query with below details-

I have three tables

1) Booking table with column booking_id , journey_start_datetime , journey_end_datetime.

2) Driver table with column driver driver_id , driver_name.

3) Driver_Assign table with column booking_id, driver_id, busy_start_datetime, busy_end_datetime.

When I assign a booking to driver a new entry goes to Driver_Assign table  with details of booking_id , journey_start_datetime , journey_end_datetime.

I want to get all the drivers name who are not busy for a given time. ie

Lets one booking is assign to a driver "John" for journey_start_datetime->'2014-06-27 12:00:00' and journey_end_datetime->'2014-06-27 14:00:00'.

Now for new booking (journey_start_datetime->'2014-06-27 13:00:00' and journey_end_datetime->'2014-06-27 15:00:00') the driver John will not come.

Moving the OP's code from comment to the question -

```
SELECT U.driver_name 
FROM driver AS U 
where U.id not in 
 (select driver_id 
  from driver_assign as DVA 
  WHERE ('2014-06-27 13:00:00'>= DVA.busy_start_datetime OR 
         '2014-06-27 13:00:00'<= DVA.busy_end_datetime
        ) AND 
        ('2014-06-27 15:00:00'>= DVA.busy_start_datetime OR 
         '2014-06-27 15:00:00'=< DVA.busy_end_datetime
        )
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT d.driver_name 
FROM driver d 
     LEFT JOIN driver_assign da ON da.driver_id=d.driver_id
WHERE
     da.busy_start_datetime <='2014-06-27 13:00:00'
    AND da.busy_end_datetime>='2014-06-27 13:00:00'
HAVING da.driver_id is null
```

You need just LEFT JOIN and exclude rows which are not nulls (busy)

Comment: Will busy_start_datetime and busy_end_datetime be same ie '2014-06-27 13:00:00'?

Comment: You can pass the date you need to be free in the both conditions

Comment: Sorry this is not working :( Do you have other option ? Plz suggest.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT d.driver_name 
FROM driver d
WHERE d.driver_id not in
(SELECT driver_id from driver_assign  
    WHERE
(busy_start_datetime >= '2014-06-27 13:00:00' AND NOT busy_start_datetime >= '2014-06-27 15:00:00')  
    OR
(busy_end_datetime > '2014-06-27 13:00:00' AND NOT busy_end_datetime > '2014-06-27 15:00:00'
)
OR (busy_start_datetime < '2014-06-27 13:00:00' AND busy_end_datetime > '2014-06-27 15:00:00')
)
```

Comment: Actually there is another OR which will need to be added, which is where a period in the driver_assign table is contained completely within the period you are checking against. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Just an idea: do you actually need the driver_assign table? You could just put a driver_id field in the booking table.